# Possible clang compiler bug with thread_local in templates

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, c++14, clang++

In my project I need separate thread-local storage for each instance of a data member. Because I ran into problems while implementing this functionality, I extracted a simplified version of the code into the following C++14 program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

template<class T> class ThreadLocalMember
{
public:
    T& local() { return store.map[this]; }
private:
    struct Store
    {
        Store() { std::cout << "construct" << std::endl; }
        ~Store() { std::cout << "destruct" << std::endl; }
        std::unordered_map<ThreadLocalMember<T>*, T> map;
    };
    static thread_local Store store;
};

template <class T> thread_local typename ThreadLocalMember<T>::Store ThreadLocalMember<T>::store;

int main()
{
    ThreadLocalMember<int> counter;
    std::cout << "point 1" << std::endl;
    int result = counter.local();
    std::cout << "point 2; result: " << result << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

The expected output is

```
point 1
construct
point 2; result: 0
destruct
```

However, when compiled with clang Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1) on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4 using

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -O3 ThreadLocalMember.cpp -o test
```

(or with `-O1` or `-O2`) the output is:

```
point 1
Illegal instruction: 4
```

It seems that the constructor of the thread_local variable is never executed and the program crashes when the variable is first accessed.

The problem goes away when

- the program is compiled without optimisation (which is not acceptable in production mode)
- the template class is replaced by a regular class (a possible workaround but very annoying)
- the thread_local keyword is removed in both places (but then the program no longer does what I need it to do when there are multiple threads)

The program also compiles and runs fine when using gcc 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16, with or without optimisation flag.

Is there something wrong with my code, or am I looking at a clang compiler bug?

Comment: Your program runs fine with the latest experimental clang 7.0

Comment: 1. Does the program work with `-O2`? 2. If your "per-thread map from objects to data" doesn't work, as a workaround, you can employ a "per-object map from threads to data": `std::map<std::thread::id, T>` in each object.

Comment: @Angew Item 1: optimisation levels `-O1` and `-O2` also break the program (with clang). Item 2: thanks for the hint; however, this solution requires locking the map upon each access unless you can pre-populate it for all threads (which I can't)

Comment: The info about `-O1` and `-O2` is very relevant, you might want to [edit] it in. That's because `-O3` is known to occasionally produce incorrect code.